# How does the compiler interpret this expression?

Tags: c++, expression, increment

While reading through a C++ book, I came across an expression which was not explained properly (or maybe I just didn't understand the explanation). This is the expression:

```
c = a+++b;
```

Which of these does it mean?

```
c = a + (++b);  // 1

c = (a++) + b;  // 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: @DeadMG, I couldn't say it better.  I don't get the point of asking what some section of obfuscated code does, unless you are trying to decipher the code of someone else who was rightfully fired.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what the resulting values of a, b and c are?

Comment: why not just run the code and see what happens? g++ interprets it as in your second example. I think for lack of other rules it interprets the expression simply from left to right.

Comment: @DeadMG, @Rocky Triton, what is dumb about it? I don't understand the comment. What do you mean obfuscated? That expression could be useful.

Comment: @afaolek: It is considered `dumb` (though I would not use that word) because you would not write that in real code (because it is unclear). The whole point of using a high level language is because it is easier to read than assembly; making it hard to read (which is the meaning of obfuscated) is counter productive. Thus the original expression is not useful (because it is hard to read), while ` c = (a++) + b;` is (slightly) more useful.

Comment: @afaolek: Obfuscated does not mean unuseful, only unnecessarily hard to read. It can be very simply transformed into something much more readable like `c = a++ + b;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its interpreted as:

```
c = a++ + b; //which is same as you're ve written : (a++) + b
```

Its following [the Maximal munch rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).

Comment: @kenny: Technically, that's different if there any UDTs with operator overloads involved...

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the answer, Nawaz.

Comment: Just say 'no' to operator overloads with that syntax.